# How to save a public html page with all media and preserve structure

Tags: css, screen-scraping, screen, directory-structure

Looking for a `Linux application` *(or Firefox extension)* that will allow me to scrape an HTML mockup and keep the page's integrity.

Firefox does an almost perfect job but doesn't grab images referenced in the CSS.

The Scrapbook extension for Firefox gets everything, but flattens the directory structure.

I wouldn't terribly mind if all folders became children of the `index` page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Website Mirroring With wget](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Services/Website-Mirroring-With-wget/1/)

```
wget --mirror –w 2 –p --HTML-extension –-convert-links http://www.yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [wget?](http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/)

Answer (score 1):

`wget -r` does what you want, and if not, there are plenty of flags to configure it. See `man wget`.

Another option is `curl`, which is even more powerful. See http://curl.haxx.se/.

Answer (score 0):

[Teleport Pro](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/pro/home.htm) is great for this sort of thing. You can point it at complete websites and it will download a copy locally maintaining directory structure, and replacing absolute links with relative ones as necessary. You can also specify whether you want content from other third-party websites linked to from the original site.